# Replace as raw string in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am replacing string content as:

```
re.sub(all, val, parsedData['outData'])
```

where `all` contains some round braces and might contain other characters.

`>>> print all
PICDSPVERS="DspFw:1.0008(1.0008),Fpga1:2.0925(2.0925),Fpga2:1.0404(1.0404),Mcu:1.0000(1.0000)"`

Because of which matching fails. The pattern is coming from some interface, so I don't want to put `\\` in the data.

I tried with 'r' and re.U option also, but still the match fails.

```
re.search('PICDSPVERS="DspFw:1.0008(1.0008)', parsedData['outData'])
```

How can we direct Python to treat a matching pattern as a string?

I am using Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the matching pattern to be treated as a regular expression, then don't use `re.sub`. For plain strings, use `str.replace()`, like so:

```
new_outData = parsedData['outData'].replace(all, val)
```